# Laravel If statement not returning data on html view

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to return a prompt of an empty data from a stripe table in database but I noticed the table data are not showing despite having data in the database also some of the html elements that are supposed to show are not showing in the view.

This my blade view

```
      <div class="row justify-content-center">
               <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12">
                 <div class="card bg-light">
                     <h3 class="card-header">Your Subscription Status</h3>
                 <div class="card-body">
                     <table class="table">
                        @if($user->subscribed())
                           <h3>Your are Subscribed</h3>
                       @else
                       <a href="{{ url('/billing') }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-mini">Subscribe Now</a>
                       @endif

                       @if($user->subscribed())
                          <thead>
                            <tr>
                              <th scope="col">Start Date</th>
                              <th scope="col">Status</th>
                              <th scope="col">Subscription Code</th>
                            </tr>
                          </thead>
                          <tbody>
                           <tr>
                             <td>{{ $staff->created_at }}</td>
                             <td>{{ $staff->stripe_status }}</td>
                             <td>{{ $staff->stripe_id }}</td>
                           </tr>
                          </tbody>
                          @else
                          <p>You are not subscribed</p>
                          @endif
                          </table>
                        <div class="row justify-content-end">
                          @if($user->subscribed())
                            <a href="{{ url('/cancel') }}" class="btn btn-danger btn-mini ">Cancel Subscription</a>
                          @endif
                       </div>
                     </div>
                   </div>
                </div>
              </div>
           </div>
```

This is my Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
use App\User;
use Session;
use Auth;
use DB;

class SubscribeController extends Controller
{
 public function viewSubscription() {

        $user = auth()->user();
        $user_id = auth()->user()->id;
        $staff = DB::table('subscriptions')->where('user_id', $user_id)->first();

        return view('subscribe.view_subscription')->with(compact('user', 'staff'));
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `subscribed()` on `$user->subscribed()`?

Comment: ```subscribed()```  is the method used in stripe for checking if a user subscribed for a plan or not. ```$user->subscribed()``` is used to check if an authenticated user is subscribed or not.

Comment: $user->subscribed() is NULL OR 0 and that's why blade doesn't return anything!
Try to {{ dd($user->subscribed()) }} in blade and see what you get

Comment: It is returning false. It was returning before but I don,t know what went wrong. Also some of the html elements are not even showing even when I get the conditional statements removed.

Comment: `$user->subscribed()` is false, you answered your own question?